# How would I post this form using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have the form all set up exactly as demo here: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/jquery/login-box-modal-dialog-window/index.html But I have no idea how to post the username and password in order to be processed by my jQuery. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Take a look at the AJAX jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: ...that plus the `serialize` function

Comment: If you mean you want to get the data back to your main website, use AJAX. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ You can bind a function to jQuery.ajaxSuccess() to get your PHP result back.

Answer (score 1):

You should post the specific code you are having trouble with, but I think this will help:

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit.button', function () {
    $.post('/signin', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function (data) {
        //check success or failure
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer so far not just posting a link and off course for it being a useful answer too.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl not to mention the fact that the asker also just posted a link

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. Much easier because you only have 2 fields. Thanks

```
jQuery('.submit.button').click(function(){ 
 var username = jQuery(this).find('#username').val(); 
 var password = jQuery(this).find('#password').val(); 

 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    data:{username:username, password: password},
    type: "post",
    success: function(html) {
           //add success function here
    },
    error: function(html) {
       //add error login here
},
    statusCode: {
     404: function() {
       //404 here
     }
    }
});

});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Won't that not work on that particular form because its a button, not input:
`<button class="submit button" type="button">Sign in</button>`

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks. I'll edit it as .click.

Comment: `$("#.submit.button").click(function() {`??

Comment: Yeah, no problem at all.